# sqlalchemy listens_for happening before table is fully created

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have noticed the listens_for decorator for sqlalchemy starts before the table is fully created, at least in my code. What should I be doing in order to make sure it starts after. Let me know if you need further code.

The error is

> Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError
> (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable) relation "organization" does not exist

My database session is created in database.py

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(current_app.config['DATABASE_URL'])

db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(
    autocommit=False,
    autoflush=False,
    bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    from . import models
    Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

@current_app.teardown_appcontext
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    db_session.remove()
```

My model is created in models.py

```
class BaseModel(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    created_on = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    updated_on = Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())

class BaseModelId(BaseModel):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Organization(BaseModelId):
    __tablename__ = 'organization'
    name = Column(String(128))
```

The issue comes from the decorator listens_for

```
@event.listens_for(Organization.__table__, 'after_create')
def insert_organizations(*args, **kwargs):
    db_session.add(Organization(
        name='organization',
    ))
    db_session.commit()
```

If I put some logging in, the event is called before `Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` finishes

The error message goes away if I allow a second or two to pass by using Timer

```
def insert_organizations(*args, **kwargs):
    Timer(2, _insert_organizations).start()

def _insert_organizations():
    db_session.add(Organization(
        name='organization',
    ))
    db_session.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `Base.metadata.create_all` is using a different connection than `db_session`, so when `commit()` is called in the event listener `create_all`'s transaction has yet to commit.

The event listener receives both the table object and the connection being used by `create_all`, so we can use those objects to insert the record instead of the session.

```py
@sa.event.listens_for(Organization.__table__, 'after_create')
def insert_organizations(tbl, conn, **kw):
    conn.execute(tbl.insert().values(name='organisation'))
```